# Type is not expected, and no contract can be inferred with .NET predefined class with protobuf-net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, protobuf-net

I have a cache of collection of [System.Globalization.CultureInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) class in my Context wrapper class

```
public Collection<System.Globalization.CultureInfo> Cultures
{
    get
    {
        // Get the value from Redis cache
    }
    set
    {
        // Save the value into Redis cache
    }
}
```

It can be accessed via *MyContextWrapper.Current.Cultures*.

I am getting the following error while serializing the value of "Collection Cultures" with [protobuf-net](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net):

**Type is not expected, and no contract can be inferred**: System.Globalization.CultureInfo

[image]

I am aware of the fact that protobuf-net needs [ProtoContract] and [ProtoMember] decoration on class but that is possible only for custom user defined classes.

How can I go with .NET predefined class then for example System.Globalization.CultureInfo in my case.

Is this even possible with protobuf-net?

Comment: Why are you serializing culture-info's?

Comment: Did my answer help you? Let me know if there's anything I should add.

Answer (score 3):

You could go with a surrogate. Notify protobuf-net of it before you serialize the Collection. Though what I have now only works with the built-in cultures, you can extend it yourself to add addtional data to fully restore the culture back.

**Example**

The surrogate to convert CultureInfo into a protobuf-net supported type.

```
[ProtoContract]
public class CultureInfoSurrogate
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int CultureId { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator CultureInfoSurrogate(CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (culture == null) return null;
        var obj = new CultureInfoSurrogate();
        obj.CultureId = culture.LCID;
        return obj;
    }

    public static implicit operator CultureInfo(CultureInfoSurrogate surrogate)
    {
        if (surrogate == null) return null;
        return new CultureInfo(surrogate.CultureId);
    }
}
```

Put this somewhere at the start of the program (at least before you are serializing the Collection):

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(CultureInfo), false).SetSurrogate(typeof(CultureInfoSurrogate));
```

If you have further questions, let me know in the comments.